# Authorize is not authenticating action asp.net core 2.0 with cookies

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am building a web app in Asp.net core 2.0 mvc-template i set the ExpireTimeSpan to 365 Days but when i close the browser and after few minutes  i came back to the site ,
it redirect me to the login path, i check  the cookies where stored in the browser
and i see the cookie is set to 365 Days later,here my implication where did i make a mistake?

> in my ConfigureServices methode:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlite("Data Source=DataBaseContext.db"));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(option =>
               {
                   option.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                   option.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
                   option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                   option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                   option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                   option.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
               }
            )
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 
                  services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(Option => {
            Option.LoginPath = "/Account/UserChalenge";
            Option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            Option.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddDetection();
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider().AddCookieTempDataProvider();
        services.AddSession();


    }
```

> and in Configure methode :

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env )
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();
       // ... use mvc template

        });


    }
```

Comment: in local server thats works fine but in host is not work

Comment: Where is your `services.AddAuthentication()` configuration?

Comment: hi thanks, i add this line  befor  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie but dosent work :

Comment: the question is why in my local iis express it works good but in host dosent work ? is it related to iis idel timout restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just contact your hosting provider to set Load user profile=true in iis setting